# Marking text in inputField by dragging mouse

Tags: javascript, events, input, focus, gojs

I got a very particular problem. Explaining it in text would proof difficult for me.
[image]

In this picture, there is a input field left of the "X" below the "1". In order to mark the number and change the whole value at once, many people would do the following:

- Put the mouse at the location of the "X" below the "1"
- Press left mouse button down
- Drag to the left until reaching the point somwhere near the "X" below the "2"
- Release the left mouse button

For whatever reasons, the number is not focused anymore after releasing the mouse inside the canvas (the grey area is a goJS canvas)

Releasing the mouse in the blue area (a few pixels left of the "900") marks the text though.

Something I considered already: the canvas has drag and drop support. Maybe it has to do with that.

Comment: Your hunch is probably correct. Probably the blue nav has a `mouseup` and `mousedown` event handlers, that are separate from the goJS canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the mouse-up event in the GoJS Diagram causes the diagram to get focus.

Try this override of **ToolManager.doMouseUp**:

```
      $(go.Diagram, . . .,
          { . . .,
            "toolManager.doMouseUp": function() {
              if (!this.isActive) return;
              go.ToolManager.prototype.doMouseUp.call(this);
            }
          });
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly what I needed!